# Android application using Volley

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, android-volley

I try to connect a server with my android application
I want to access my api, making a POST request with volley by post json object.

```
{
"username" : "admin",
"rememberMe" : true,
"password" : "admin"
}
```

The web service give you a id_token if the user really exist to connect. the web service is already exist. I try to use Volley library for Android application.

this my source code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText usermail;
EditText userPassword;
Button signInButton;
TextView signUpTextview;
Button signInFacebook;
byte userType;


String loginApi="http://192.168.100.28:8080/api/authenticate";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    usermail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.signInMail);
    userPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.signInPassword);
    signInButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
    signUpTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.signUpTextView);
    signInFacebook = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signInFacebook);


    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           boolean connected = ConnectionService.checkConnection(getApplicationContext());
            if(!connected){
                ToastOX.Tnull(getApplicationContext(), "A network error has occurred");
                return;
                }

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", "admin");
            params.put("rememberMe", "true");
            params.put("password", "password");

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(params);

            JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginApi,jsonObj ,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    String id_token = null;
                    try {
                        id_token = response.getString("id_token");
                        Log.d("nizarab",id_token);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("nizarab","erreur");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),id_token,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    //TODO: handle failure
                    Log.e("!_@@_Error::>",error.toString());
                }
            });


            VolleyParce.getInstance(MainActivity.this).add(stringRequest);


        }
    });



}  }
```

but I don't receive the id_token 
this is my log errors

> 01-24 17:32:07.051 26319-27109/com.nizar.talquest10 E/Volley: [40066] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://192.168.100.28:8080/api/authenticate
>   01-24 17:32:07.051 26319-27114/com.nizar.talquest10 E/Volley: [40071] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://192.168.100.28:8080/api/authenticate
>   01-24 17:32:07.051 26319-26319/com.nizar.talquest10 W/System.err: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
>   01-24 17:32:07.061 26319-26319/com.nizar.talquest10 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:171)
>   01-24 17:32:07.061 26319-26319/com.forsyslab.talquest10 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
>   01-24 17:32:07.061 26319-26319/com.forsyslab.talquest10 E/!_@@_Error::>: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

Comment: You forgot to ask the question.

Comment: sorry I edit it

Comment: The error is very clear. You are getting response code 401 which means access is denied due to invalid credentials

Comment: I just write the rang password thx Prerak